# How to find the possible measurements of a quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, measurements

A wave function of an infinite square well is given as 
$$ \psi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5a}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right) +\frac{2}{\sqrt{5a}}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi x}{a}\right),\quad x\in[0,a] $$
How do I find the possible results of the measurement of the system's energy and the corresponding probabilities?

Comment: This question clearly asks about a specific physics concept, i.e. identifying the possible outcomes of a QM measurement. I don't understand why this is put on hold?

Answer (score 4):

In order to find the energies and corresponding probabilities, it's best to rewrite the expression in terms of eigenfunctions. The eigenfunctions of the infinite square well between $x=0$ and $x=a$ are

$$ \phi_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}} \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right). $$

Using these, your wave function is

$$ \psi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\phi_1(x) + \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}\phi_3(x). \tag{1}$$

The coefficients in front of the eigenfunctions are the probability amplitudes. The absolute square of those yields the probability.

So the probability of measuring $E_1$ is $p_1=1/10$ and the probability of measuring $E_3$ is $p_3=2/5$.

...but wait, they don't add up to one. Instead, $p_1+p_3=1/2$. This indicates that our wave function was not normalized. So let's do it again, but first we normalize Eq. (1):

$$ \psi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\phi_1(x) + \frac{2}{\sqrt 5}\phi_3(x) $$

Now we can read off the amplitudes again as $a_1 = 1/\sqrt 5$ and $a_3=2/\sqrt 5$. Squaring them yields the probabilities: $p_1=1/5=20\%$ to get $E_1$ and $p_3=4/5=80\%$ to get $E_3$.

And you probably know that the energies are

$$ E_n = \frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2ma^2}. $$

Comment: Thanks!! I think you meant P1 + P3 should add up to 1.

Comment: Yes of course, thanks.